# Parallel write access in Waterline

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm calling a REST API for updating my database entries in sails.
Therefore i have a function which iterates over an JSON Array and calls for each entry another function which saves the values into a database.

```
function getData(){
 for(index in apiJson){
   saveData(apiJSON[index]);
 }
}
```

In the saveData function I use the .findOrCreate functionality from waterline. If there is not such an entry a new one is created. This all works pretty fine. But now i want to append the id from the new created entry (Table: match) to an array (`matches`) in another table (Table: team). There i getting some failures because of the asynchronous behavior of JavaScript.

My implementation (in short) looks like the following:

```
Match.findOrCreate({..},{..}).exec(function(err,match){
    ...
    //if match was just created in db
    if(newMatch){
      Team.findOrCreate({apiID: someTeamID}),
      {
        ...
        ...,
        matches: []
      }
      ).exec(function(err,team){        
        team.matches.push(someID);
        team.save(function(err,s){
         ...          
        });
      });
    }
});
```

Since JavaScript executes this code asynchronously i get duplicate entries of teams in my model Team. Also my array `matches` in model Team does not correspond to my values in the other model Match.

How can i sort of serialize the database write accesses to prevent this behavior? Is there a possibility to let the loop run in parallel but the database updates in serial?

Answer (score 1):

`Sails.js` provides async as a [global variable](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/sails.config/sails.config.globals.md), you can use it to do the serialize operation like following

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
       callback(null, 'data1');
    },
    function(callback){
       //handle data
       callback(null, 'data2');
    }
], function(err, results) {
      res.send(results.data1 + results.data2);
});
```